# Get value of object in json file if var is equal to object name - python

Tags: json, python-3.x, card

I have a function that sees what card is in a player's hand and will add to their score depending on the card in their hand. I have all the card values stored in a JSON file. I have code this so far:

```
with open("values.json") as values:
    value = json.load(values)
    for i in range(0, len(hand)):
        card = hand[i]
```

values.json

```
{
    "3Hearts": 3
}
```

if the card is `3Hearts` how could I get the 3 to be returned?
Or is there a better way to store the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will admit I am not very familiar with json files. However if the json file is not a necessity you could just store the data in another .py file (Cards.py for example).

Also, because you are using python, you would be better off making a `Card class` and make `Card objects`.
This is what it would look like:

```
    # Make Card Class
    class Card:
        def __init__(self, name, number):
            self.name = name
            self.number = number


    # Make Card Objects
    threehearts = Card("3Hearts", "3")
```

Here I used `threehearts` instead of `3Hearts` because making an object name starting with a number is not good practice. To compensate I made an attribute `Card.name` where you can "name" the card `"3Hearts"` as you did in the question.

So assuming you are going to use that .py file to store your data, this is what I would propose:

```
    # Import data here
    from Cards import*

    # Make the player's hand
    hand = [threehearts]

    # Display the number corresponding to the player's hand
    for i in range(0, len(hand)):
        card = hand[i]
        print(card.number)
```

The output of this code will be:

```
    3
```

You can also store `hand = [threehearts]` in the Cards.py file as well if you need to.